# The default route is not added by rmnet interface when the WiFi interfaces are UP

Tags: routes, wifi, router, openwrt, cellular-network

I'm developing a router, that uses a sim-card for the WAN connection.
When the rmnet interface is up and WiFi interfaces are down, the default route is created successfully:

```
root@OpenWrt:/# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.59.127.70    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 rmnet_data0
```

But **when the WiFi interfaces are up as well, the default route is absent in the routing table**.
Of course, I can add it manually and 'ping' the network, but it is not a solution.

I can't even imagine where the problem can be.

I will be very grateful for any ideas and advice.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. It is in WiFi configuration.
I have WPS enabled by default on every WiFi interface.
That affects in some way the rmnet interfaces (or routing tables).
However, if WPS is disabled by default the default route is created successfully.
I will continue investigation.